# Sinatra assetpack not compiling sass to css

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sinatra-assetpack

I have a basic Sinatra app and I am attempting to use AssetPack to serve my assets. I am currently only trying to serve css files from sass files. I am including the sass gem.

Snippit from my app.rb file:

```
register Sinatra::AssetPack

assets {
  css :application, '/css/application.css', [
    '/css/styles.sass'
  ]

  css_compression :sass
}
```

I am using slim so I have:

```
== css :application
```

For what ever reason, no css file is generated, only the sass file gets served.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have `gem 'sass'` in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 2):

So make sure you are including `<%= css :application %>` in your layout file you want the CSS to load on.

You also want to make sure the gem is being loaded with `gem 'sass'` in your gemfile.

Also make sure your app root is set correctly in your main app file with `set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)`

**Another reason may be you are running Sinatra in DEVELOPMENT mode. Try setting your RACK_ENV to PRODUCTION, or set your development environment in rubymine to PRODUCTION.**

Sinatra asset pack *will not* compress the file unless you run it through production, so that may be the main issue. I assume right now it serves up the SASS file with a cache buster appended to it?